# One to many relationship does not insert parent

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a one to many relationship. When I select, select works correctly but when trying to make an insert, the insert occurs in the main table but in others occurs an update.

#### log generated in the console

```
[0] query: BEGIN TRANSACTION

[0] query: INSERT INTO "tblCategory"("ID_CATEGORY", "NM_CATEGORY") VALUES (@0, @1)
-- PARAMETERS: [{"value":"BDA9A127-0851-4E2D-8FC7-52FBF27CFDF4","type":"uniqueidentifier","params":[]},{"value":Test,"type":"nvarchar","params":[]}]

[0] query: UPDATE "tblBook" SET "ID_CATEGORY" = @1 WHERE "ID_BOOK" = @0
-- PARAMETERS: ["F5465876-8003-44A6-BF97-9CBBE6D30C92",{"value":"BDA9A127-0851-4E2D-8FC7-52FBF27CFDF4","type":"uniqueidentifier","params":[]}]

[0] query: COMMIT
```

#### expectation

For the table tblCategory generates the insert correctly, I need the table tblBook to generate the insert and not the update as it is occurring.

#### [Code](https://gist.github.com/viniciusvelasco/a50b1c324b1d711ec8ef36a031c893e1)

author.entity.ts

```
@Entity('tblCategory')
export class Category {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'ID_CATEGORY', type: 'uniqueidentifier' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'NM_CATEGORY', type: 'nvarchar' })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => Book, book => book.category)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'tblBook',
    joinColumn: { name: 'ID_BOOK' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'ID_CATEGORY' },
  })
  books: Book[];

}
```

category.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ForragemPastoService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Category)
    private readonly repository: Repository<Category>,
  ) {}

  async save(category: Category): Promise<Category> {
    await this.repository.save(category);
    const data = await this.repository.findOne(category.id, {
      relations: ['books'],
    });
    return data;
  }
}
```

book.entity.ts

```
@Entity('tblBook')
export class Book {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'ID_BOOK', type: 'uniqueidentifier' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'DS_TITLE', type: 'nvarchar' })
  title: string;

  @Column({ name: 'DS_SUBTITILE', type: 'nvarchar' })
  subtitle: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, m => m.books)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'ID_CATEGORY' })
  category: Category;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vinícius, welcome to Stackoverflow! :-) Please edit your question and add the code from your gist link. The link might expire someday, so it's important to have all necessary information in your thread. Also, try to make clearer, what your expectation is and what actually happens instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the cascading? It may help:

```
@OneToMany(type => Book, book => book.category, {cascade: true})
```